# Load simulator for RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, load-testing

We need to run load tests on our infrastructure.  Our data path uses RabbitMQ (RMQ) to distribute messages to a cluster running our in-house message processing code.  For each simulated user, we need to send a 3KB message every five seconds to our RMQ broker. Our goal is to test 5K users, with plans to work up to 25K+ simulated users.

Aside: our data stream is time-series data and the messages must be sent in ordered sequence to make sense to the processing code.  We have recordings of this data and plan to stream the data for each user from one of these recordings.  Furthermore, each message must have the correct binding and attributes assigned for that user.

We have been planning to build this load simulator from scratch in Java, but the user count complicates the details.  For example, it is easy to create a Timer for each user with a 5 second repeat period, but will Java handle 5K or 25K timers?  The compute load for each user is tiny (send an 3KB message to RMQ; sleep for 5s; repeat) but there are a lot of them.  On the other hand, 16 and 32 core machines are available on AWS.

Alternatively, there are plenty of open-source load simulators.  However there are few that work with RMQ and even fewer that would let us define per-user bindings and attributes.  That said, I have probably missed some.

So the question: What is best-practice for generating timed messages for 5K to 25K parallel data streams?  I would prefer to use Java, but am open to alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest a different approach to building such a tool.

So you say, there must be 5K users, each user should have 3KB message generated every 5 seconds. Example:

```
User 1: msg1_time = 12:00:00.000, msg2_time = 12:00:05.000, msg3_time = 12:00:10.000, etc.
```

Now the question is what happens for the second user, and all other users in general: will they run simultaneously and have the same message times? Or it should be kind of random with some small "offset"?

In any of these cases, let's call this offset for each user EPS (epsilon), if you hard-coded put it to 0 they'll run in the same time, and if you do some randomized small value per user you simulate the "offset per user".

Now here is my point.

Once you "set up" the initial time for the user - you can calculate the time for the next message if you keep the count of the number of sent messages per user K:

```
If msg0_time = 12:00:00 + EPS 
Then: msg1_time = mgs0_time + 1 * 5 sec  // here K = 1 
Then: msg2_time = msg0_time + 2 * 5 sec  // K = 2 because we've sent two messages
...   and so on ...
```

With this in mind, you can run a busy loop in only one thread that will check whether the "time has come" to send the message and will off-load the actual loading to some thread pool of N threads that will only send the messages and increase the K per user

In a java-like pseudo-code it will look something like this:

```
class UserData {
   UUID userId;      // or maybe other user details
   long seedTime;    // init with the same seed for all users or with random EPS offset
   int sentMsgsCount; // in real life probably use AtomicInteger or something 
   boolean inProcess; 

   boolean isInProcess() {
      return inProcess;
   }
   void markMessageSending() {
      this.inProcess = true;
   } 
   void messageSent () {
      this.sentMsgCount++;
      this.inProcess = false;
   }
} 

List<UserData> allData =  generateDataForNUsers(5_000); // generate data for N users
```

```
while(true) { // run forever or maybe until some total message count like 1000 * 5000  - so that 1000 messages will be sent for each user
   long time = now();
   List<UserData> usersToProcess = 
   allData.filter(time > userData.seedTime + userData.sentMsgCount * 5 second) 
          .filter(!userData.isInProcess);
   submitMessageSendingForUsersToThreadPool(usersToProcess); // mark as "in-process" in the same thread and submit to the thread - pool
}
```

The job in the thread pool will take the user data which has been already marked as "in-process", generate the actual message, and send it to the RMQ, then it will call `userData.messageSent` to make it available for further checks.

Answer (score 1):

Java should be able to "handle" the "timers" as long as JVM has sufficient resources (CPU, RAM, Heap, GC, etc.)  given you [properly tune it for the performance](https://javaperformancetuning.com/)

To be on the safe side I would rather recommend choosing a load testing tool, there is quite a number of [free and open source load testing tools](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) and the majority of them supports parameterization and running in [clustered mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster) when you have several load generators installed on different machines if the single one isn't able to conduct the required load.

For example [Gatling](https://gatling.io/) allows creating tests in Scala (Java code can also be used), it doesn't support RabbitMQ out of the box however it's possible to create an [extension](https://gatling.io/docs/current/extensions/), for example you can use [AMQP Plugin](https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/gatling-amqp-plugin) as the reference